# JQuery conditional submit after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit

1) The form submit action is changed by the document ready fn to make an ajax call

2) If the data from the ajax is not 'No probs' then it puts the error message in a div and changes the value of the submit, so that a second click takes you to the standard action.
This bit works.

3) If there is not an error I want it to post the standard action:
See `alert('Fred1');`  (here I have tried `$('#addcreditdetails').submit()` also

I have tried lots of things but cannot get 3) to work.

```
    <script>

    var chrisReady = function () {

     var submitFunction = function (event) {
      //console.log(submitval);

      var chrisPoster = function (data) {
       alert(data);
       if (data=='No probs') {
        $('#dealwarning').html('CC');
        alert('Fred1');
        $('#addcreditdetails').unbind('submit');
        $('#addcreditdetails').submit();
        alert('Fred2');
       }
       else {
        $('#dealwarning').html(data);
        $('#submit').val('Confirm Add Credit');
        jQuery('#addcreditdetails').unbind('submit');
       }
      };

      var amountval = $('#amount').val();
      var currval = $('#curr').val();
      var accountnoval = $('#accountno').val();
      var submitval = $('#submit').val();


      var postData = { 
       amount: amountval,
       curr: currval,
       accountno: accountnoval,
       submit: submitval
      };

      $.post('docheckcredit.php', postData, chrisPoster);
     }

     $('#addcreditdetails').bind('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      submitFunction(event);
     });
    }

$(document).ready(chrisReady);
</script>";
```

Comment: Watch the "; after your </script> tag.

Comment: @DN I would say it's from some PHP/ASP.net dynamic including

Answer (score 0):

Could you try replace the

```
 $('#addcreditdetails').submit();
```

to

```
 $('#addcreditdetails').first().submit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that was about three companies ago! I've forwarded it to someone it may help :-)